# error: no member named 'mi_realloc' in namespace 'std'; did you mean simply 'mi_realloc'?

Tags: c++, mimalloc

I am trying to use `mimalloc-new-delete` and `mimalloc-override`, this way:

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef _common_hpp
#define _common_hpp

#define SOL_ALL_SAFETIES_ON 1

#include <mimalloc-new-delete.h>
#include <mimalloc-override.h>

extern "C" {
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <avif/avif.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <physfs.h>
}

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <sol/sol.hpp>

#include "constants.hpp"
#include "deleters.hpp"
#include "types.hpp"

#endif
```

When I compile, I got the error

```
-- Build files have been written to: /opt/workspace/carimbolabs/carimbo/build
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/carimbo.dir/cmake_pch_arm64.hxx.pch
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /opt/workspace/carimbolabs/carimbo/build/CMakeFiles/carimbo.dir/cmake_pch_arm64.hxx:5:
In file included from /opt/workspace/carimbolabs/carimbo/src/application.hpp:5:
In file included from /opt/workspace/carimbolabs/carimbo/src/audiomanager.hpp:5:
In file included from /opt/workspace/carimbolabs/carimbo/src/common.hpp:20:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:44:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:165:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:172:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/locale:2827:22: error: no member named 'mi_realloc' in namespace 'std'; did you mean simply 'mi_realloc'?
    _Tp* __t = (_Tp*)std::realloc(__owns ? __b.get() : 0, __new_cap);
                     ^~~~~
/Users/skhaz/.conan2/p/b/mimal0a19b82323bd4/p/include/mimalloc.h:112:40: note: 'mi_realloc' declared here
mi_decl_nodiscard mi_decl_export void* mi_realloc(void* p, size_t newsize)      mi_attr_noexcept mi_attr_alloc_size(2);
                                       ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/carimbo.dir/cmake_pch_arm64.hxx.pch] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/carimbo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It also says that `#include<mimalloc-override.h>` is only reliable if you control _all_ of the code, but you are using a bunch of libraries that will do allocations. This will likely end with `free` calls on pointers from the wrong allocator.

Answer (score 2):

The line causing the error is:

```
 _Tp* __t = (_Tp*)std::realloc(__owns ? __b.get() : 0, __new_cap);
```

Notice it is calling `std::realloc`. Notice the error is:

> no member named 'mi_realloc' in namespace 'std';

That means, somewhere in this package, is a

```
#define realloc mi_realloc
```

or some such macro.

This is a terrible design exactly for the reason you are seeing now. Your package tries to reroute allocation to its own stuff.

Simplest thing to try first: move all

```
#include <mimalloc-new-delete.h>
#include <mimalloc-override.h>
```

to be the very last include in the include list. And don't include those from any header files. Maybe that will work. Also, don't try precompiled headers or any sort of bulk build.

Comment: If I move, they will not be replaced. I thought the idea is to have above of all includes to overwrite the new/delete/free/malloc.

Comment: Those in your code will be